# Definition of a modified scheduling problem where jobs are halted based on the shifts of employees

Tags: optimization, reference-request, scheduling

I am looking for the name of a scheduling problem in literature with some references. Here is the variant that I have in mind.

Given a set of jobs, employees have certain shifts that they can work on these jobs. Suppose employee $e$ starts processing job $j$ on machine $m$, but before completing the job, his shift finishes. The rule is that no other job can replace $j$ until its process is completed. That is why either the same employee or another employee should come and continue working on $j$ based on their shift requirements.

I was wondering how this problem is defined / called and if there are efficient formulation proposed for it in the literature. I am aware of the preemptive scheduling, but my problem definition is a little bit different than it.

Comment: This is not exactly what you described, but maybe it is a good starting point: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305054808001445

Comment: @EnriqueGabrielBaquela I had read this paper before posting my queston and as you mentioned, this is not what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest topic of what you described that I am aware of is the field of "Scheduling with machine availability constraints". In particular, the semiresumable case:

> Under the semiresumable assumption, the disrupted operation will have to partially restart after the machine becomes available again

Here is a not so recent survey of these problems:

- "A survey of scheduling with deterministic machine availability constraints" (Ma et al, 2010) [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cie.2009.04.014)

Answer (score -1):

As you pointed out this is not a case that preemption would help. The preemptive constraint is often used where we are still allowed to split a job/task if another job/task with higher priority needs to be processed on the same machine/resource. In this case, the on-hand processed task would be stopped or moved to another machine/resource (splitting the processing task) to process the new one with higher priority.

Now, I assume there are no other constraints on the problem you mentioned. The scheduling model you are having is a variant of the [Parallel machine scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_task_scheduling) with the resourced constraints. $ \text{P}_{m} ||  \sum w_{j}c_{j} \ Or \ C_{max}$. Also, As far as I know, the problem is classified as NP-Hard in the Ordinary Sense$^1$.

The $ \text{P}_{m} || C_{max}$ can already be solved efficiently by applying ***LPT*** (The Longest Processing Time first) rule. Also, one of its practical forms in presence of the machine eligibility constraint would be ***LFJ/LFM*** (the Least Flexible Job/Machine first). Besides the mentioned algorithms it would be worth taking a look at MILP, CP, etc. to solve such a problem in an optimal sense.

To assign employees to the machines in each shift, either [rough cut capacity planning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/crp/rccp.htm#:%7E:text=RCCP%20verifies%20that%20you%20have,schedule%20and%2For%20available%20capacity.) (RCCP) or the simulation method would be useful. Please, be aware that it is still usual that at the end of each shift, some WIPs/jobs would be remaining or being under process till another operator comes to complete that. Such times are often called the chang-over time and can be assumed as planned stop time.

---

$^1$ - [Scheduling Algorithms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-69516-5)

Answer (score -4):

It can be solved by mathematical optimization. I'd go by below:
Define variable $ x_{j,m}^t$ where $t$ represents the shift
If $D_j$ is the processing time for job $j$ & $ S_t$ is shift duration at $t$ then you need a constraint like
$ D_j \le Ux_{j,m}^{t+1} + \sum_{k\le t}x_{j,m}^kS_k$
and
$ \sum_{k\le t}x_{j,m}^kS_k - D_j \le U(1-x_{j,m}^{t+1})$
where binary variable $ x_{j,m}^t=1$ if job $j$ is assigned to machine $m$ at time $t$, else 0 and
$U$ is a large number, not too large just based on the scle of the model, could be upper bound of something like sum of all shift durations.
Also
$ \sum_j x_{j,m}^t \le 1$: ensures one job per machine at a time

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your proposation. Say the processing time is $5$ and I start working on the job at $t=4$. Suppose my shift is over at $t=6$ and another employee starts his shift at $t=7$ and work on it until $t=10$ and completes the job. How do your constraints or variables capture this behavior?

Comment: Does it make sense now? If processing at at end of time instance, $t$ is still more than the shift durations for which it was assigned, then it will be assigned to next shift